# Code to include longer file name where the file name is a number

Tags: vba, excel, directory, create-directory

I am trying to edit code that someone else wrote.  I have done NO VBA and very little coding in general.

The original code is written for a 5 digit number and we now have files that are six digits.  I have tried to copy the code but change it to 6 digit numbers below the current code above `Next objFile` at the end.  This has not worked.

The main issue here is I didn't write the original code and I don't understand the logic.  I have tried just changing all of the 5's to 6's and the 99999 to 999999.  I have tried copying from Folder = "" down, changing them to 6 digits and pasting below `Next objFile`.  This didn't work either.

```
Sub CopyPics()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim objSubFolder As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

Dim Dest As String
Dest = "R:\Field Assurance\FA PHOTOS AND INFORMATION\"

'Loop through each file in this folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    Folder = "" 'Empty old folder name
    MainFolder = "" 'Empty old folder name
    For i = 1 To Len(objFile.Name)
        Test = Mid(objFile.Name, i, 5)
        If Test >= 10000 And Test <= 99999 Then     'For files: Find any five numbers in a row and assume it to be the file number.
            Folder = "NC-" & Mid(objFile.Name, i, 5) 'If found, create new folder.
            i = Len(objFile.Name) 'In other words, take the first 5 numbers, then get out.
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders 'Find the main folder.
    If Right(Folder, 5) >= Mid(objSubFolder.Name, 4, 5) And Right(Folder, 5) <= Mid(objSubFolder.Name, 18, 5) Then 'If my file number is within the main folder bounds...
    MainFolder = objSubFolder.Name & "\" 'Use that folder.
    End If
    Next objSubFolder

    If Len(Folder) = 8 And Len(MainFolder) = 23 Then 'If real folders are identified...

    On Error Resume Next
    If Dir(Dest & MainFolder & Folder) = "" Then 'Check to see if the directory/folder does not exist...
        objFSO.CreateFolder (Dest & MainFolder & Folder) 'If not, make one.
    End If

    'Rename that file's directory to be the new one - aka cut and paste file into new folder.
    Name Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & objFile.Name As Dest & MainFolder & Folder & "\" & objFile.Name

    End If

Next objFile

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to step through with a 5 digit code and track the changes in value. It may well be that there are other dependencies such as Len(Folder) = 8 And Len(MainFolder) = 23   looks like tests on Folder length might increase if Folder = "NC-" & Mid(objFile.Name, i, 5) changes to have a 6 etc.....

Comment: The locals window will be of use and perhaps watch windows. Put one file through where it works noting the values that are being generated so you have a better idea of what is going on. There are lots of tutorials on debugging.. how to step through the code with F8, how to use the immediate window, watch window and locals window. It is an invaluable skill and is a few hours of your time to get a basic understanding.

Comment: Are *all* your files now 6 digits, or are you also dealing with 5-digit names still?

Comment: Thanks,  I want to be able to put the time in to learn all of this.  My employer doesn't feel like me spending the time to learn to edit the code is valuable at this point.  I will have to manually create the folders and move the files until I figure it out on my personal time.  I appreciate your tips.  I want to learn this.

Comment: @TimWilliams I still deal with 5 digit names.  I need to be able to handle both.

Comment: Just so it's clear, can you describe exactly what the function of the code is?  What should it do?

Comment: For example it would help to show some examples of exactly how your subfolders are named (covering both 5-digit and 6-digit cases).  Can the correct subfolder name be predicted just from the file number?

Comment: @Tim Williams 

This spreadsheet will automatically place files into their respective Nonconformance Folders.  These files can be pictures, Word docs, Excel docs, etc.  This tool will also create folders where they should be if a folder does not already exist.  The only requirement is that the file contains the NC number.  See below for instructions on how to use this tool:
1 ) Save files in current folder - "R:\Field Assurance\FA PHOTOS AND INFORMATION\".
2) Ensure the NC# is located within the file name, before other 5-digit numbers.
3) Open this file.  Press the "Execute" button.

Comment: @Tim Williams  the issue began when the subfolder was named NC-98001 thru NC-101000.  Prior subfolders were named NC-95001 thru NC-98000, NC-92001 thru NC-95000.  The sub folder with the 6-digit number is what I think is causing the issue.  I would like to rename the folder to give me some time to work but it is a group folder and people leave it open all the time.

Comment: "NC-95001 thru NC-98000" (for example) is the *exact* folder name?

Comment: R:\Field Assurance\FA PHOTOS AND INFORMATION\NC-95001 thru NC-98000\NC-97050

Would be the complete file path for NC-97050.  The files I am attempting to move in the FA PHOTOS AND INFORMATION folder into their own subfolder would have 97050 somewhere in the file name.

Comment: OK, got it.  I will have a go at this a little later...

Comment: I appreciate any assistance.  I will be working on figuring it out but it probably won't be elegant or efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more complex than your original code but I think it's more robust...

Lightly tested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPics()

    'use constants for fixed values
    Const DEST As String = "R:\Field Assurance\FA PHOTOS AND INFORMATION\"

    Dim objFSO As Object, srcFolder As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object, destFolder As Object, fNum, folderName, picFolderName
    Dim FileWasMoved As Boolean, sMsg

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set srcFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path) 'ThisWorkbook.Path ?
    Set destFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(DEST) 'parent destination folder

    'Loop through each file in this folder
    For Each objFile In srcFolder.Files

        FileWasMoved = False 'reset "moved" flag

        fNum = ExtractNumber(objFile.Name) 'get the file number

        If Len(fNum) > 0 Then 'any number found?

            folderName = "NC-" & fNum

            For Each objSubFolder In destFolder.subfolders 'Find the subfolder.
                If IsTheCorrectFolder(objSubFolder.Name, fNum) Then

                    picFolderName = objSubFolder.Path & "\" & folderName
                    If Not objFSO.folderexists(picFolderName) Then
                        objFSO.CreateFolder picFolderName
                    End If
                    'move the file
                    Name objFile.Path As picFolderName & "\" & objFile.Name
                    FileWasMoved = True 'flag file as moved
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next objSubFolder
        End If 'filename contains a number

        'if file was not moved then add it to the list....
        If Not FileWasMoved Then sMsg = sMsg & vbLf & objFile.Name

    Next objFile

    'warn user if some files were not moved
    If Len(sMsg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Some files were not moved:" & vbLf & sMsg, vbExclamation
    End If


End Sub

'Return true/false depending on whether this is the correct
'  folder to hold the specified filenumber 
Function IsTheCorrectFolder(folderName, fileNumber) As Boolean
    Dim arr, num1, num2, rv As Boolean
    rv = False 'default return value
    arr = Split(folderName, "thru") 'split folder name on "thru"
    If UBound(arr) = 1 Then 'should have two parts
        'get the numbers from each part and compare against the file number
        num1 = ExtractNumber(arr(0))
        num2 = ExtractNumber(arr(1))
        If Len(num1) > 0 And Len(num2) > 0 Then
            fileNumber = CLng(fileNumber) 'convenrt to Long for comparison
            rv = (fileNumber >= CLng(num1) And fileNumber <= CLng(num2))
        End If
    End If
    IsTheCorrectFolder = rv
End Function

'Extract the first 5- or 6-digit number from a string
' Match is "greedy" so if there are six digits it will match 6 and
'   not just the first 5...
Function ExtractNumber(txt)
    Dim re As Object, allMatches, rv
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "(\d{5,6})"
    re.ignorecase = True
    re.Global = True
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(txt)
    If allMatches.Count > 0 Then rv = allMatches(0) 'if there's a match then return the first one
    ExtractNumber = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked beautifully!!  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.  This will save me hours of folder creation and file moving.  My attempts to make it work so far have failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the lower limit in IF condition also. Like

```
If Test >= 10000 And Test <= 99999 Then
```

becomes

```
If Test >= 100000 And Test <= 999999 Then
```

Currently the loop could be exiting when it finds the first five digit number.